# Advertencia Undefined offset: 0 al acceder a los datos

Tags: php, google-api

Empezando con PHP y he realizado un código que me está dando el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\vs api3.php on line 31

Necesito descargar los datos de diferentes canales. La `id` del canal está guardada cada una en un `txt`.

Lo que quiero es que lea la `id` que hay guardada en el archivo `txt` y después descargue los datos de los suscriptores de esa `id`.

Y de paso, si pueden ayudarme a que descargue la imagen del canal de 88x88, sería un ahorro de tiempo en descubrirlo considerable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = file_get_contents("C:/topvs2.txt");
$exploded = multiexplode(array(" (","#1 ",") - #2 ",") - #3 ",") - #4 ",") - #5 ",") - #6 ",") - #7 ",") - #8 ",") - #9 ",") - #10 ",") - #11 ",") - #12 ",") - #13 ",") - #14 ",") - #15 ",") - #16 ",") - #17 ",") - #18 ",") - #19 ",") - #20 "),$text);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$id1= file_get_contents("C:/$exploded[3].txt");
$exploded1 = multiexplode(array("|"),$id1);

$channel_id = $exploded1[1];
$api_key = "MI_API_KEY";
$api_response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='.$channel_id.'&fields=items/statistics/subscriberCount&key='.$api_key);
$api_response_decoded = json_decode($api_response, true);
echo $api_response_decoded['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'];

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código es correcto, pero no estás teniendo en cuenta la posibilidad de que no exista el canal que estás consultando, por lo que te sale una advertencia indicando que no existe el primer (y teóricamente único) elemento del resultado.

Para tener en cuenta esa posibilidad deberías contar el número de elementos que te devuelve el API de Youtube:

```
<?php
// Limpiamos los datos obtenidos
$channel_id = trim($exploded1[1]);
$api_key = "MI_API_KEY";
// Consultamos el API de Youtube
$api_response = file_get_contents(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='
    . $channel_id
    . '&fields=items/statistics/subscriberCount&key='
    . $api_key
);
$api_response_decoded = json_decode($api_response, true);
// Si no existe ningún elemento en "items" es porque no se encontró el canal
if (count($api_response_decoded['items']) === 0) {
  echo 'No se encontró el canal: ', $channel_id, PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'Resultado: ', $api_response_decoded['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta. He añadido el if al código y funciona bien, no obstante todas las id que extraigo en los archivos exploded[x]  son de canales existentes. Si accedo al primer usuario នⱢⱵⲉმɱ ɭAɃȿ.txt contiene: Array ( [0] => Eterno [1] => UCc6r7XxxBgPYhK9wKqw4TPA ) Cuando extraigo la id y la imprimo si aparece correctamente, no obstante al llamar la api es cuando se produce el error y se debe a porqué por algún motivo no reconoce la id. Si buscamos https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCc6r7XxxBgPYhK9wKqw4TPA  El canal existe, la id parece que la toma bien, pero da error de indice.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir los archivos para poder reproducir el problema? Es probable que estés añadiendo espacios en blanco, nuevas líneas o incluso el BOM en el archivo, y eso hace que tengas caracteres adicionales que te hacen fallar la búsqueda. PD: usa un servicio que me permita descargar el archivo exacto como mega, google drive, etc., No me valdría un copiar/pegar del contenido.

Comment: Si, le adjunto los archivos que uso. La idea es que en topvs.php además de mostrar el nombre y los puntos, deben mostrar los suscriptores de ese usuario. el vs api3.php es con el que estoy probando y me da el error. Le adjunto el archivo de dos usuarios. Este archivo se crea automático al conectarse al chat del canal. con nombre_usuario.txt. Cada usuario tiene un txt. Con el rango y la id de youtube. Los archivos: https://mega.nz/#F!rwIikCID!1jyt2_N5fqCWM57nLVWbGQ  Gracias por su inestimable ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como me imaginaba, estás obteniendo los avances de línea `0x0a` o `\n` al final de la cadena. Con un [`trim()`](https://php.net/trim) podrás solucionarlo. Edito la respuesta.

Comment: PD: **Borra el archivo de mega** y **cambia el secreto** (la credencial o api key) en el [panel de credenciales del proyecto](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) de la consola de desarrolladores pulsando en editar en la credencial. En el archivo de mega está tu api key y alguien podría usarla maliciosamente.

Comment: Dónde le aplico el trim()? Soy muy noob. Borré el enlace. Gracias por tu consejo.

Comment: En [mi última edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/272609/revisions) está el ejemplo. Fíjate cómo asigno a `$channel_id` la salida de aplicar `trim()` al contenido de la variable `$exploded1[1]`.

Comment: Por fin! lo logramos! Cuanto tiempo dándole vueltas. Muchas gracias Oscar! Te deseo lo mejor! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, un Notice no es un error, es simplemente un aviso (ni siquiera una advertencia como el warning). En este caso es por el índice `0` que lo ha usado sin incializarlo, es decir, sin haberle asignado previamente un valor. Muestra el array antes de esta línea y verás como aún no tiene nada asignado.

Utiliza este código para ver el contenido de ese array y asegúrate de que contiene en índice `0` y añádelo a tu pregunta:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $api_response_decoded );
echo '</pre>';
```